# FlexUnit Execution Time

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit

Is there a way to know how long one test took in FlexUnit? Is there a way to know how long all tests took?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FlexUnit UI - [this article](http://www.insideria.com/2008/04/unit-testing-with-flexunit-1.html) walks through how to run it.

The UI will show you run times per test.